# How to destructure form input values from useFormikContext?

Tags: formik

I am trying to destructure `values` to get specific value of the form inputs using `useFormikContext()`

I have done like:

```
const { values } = useFormikContext()    
const { name, age } = values
```

but I'm getting error like:

> Property `'name'` does not exist on type 'unknown'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fixed it.

I'm using typescript, when I added the interface to the `useFormikContext()` the error was gone.

Did it like this:  `useFormikContext<ProfileFields>()`

Comment: Where did you get `ProfileFields` from?

Comment: @Camilo it’s the interface of the fields I defined